# Log4j2.xml configuration to turn off hibernate debug level logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Well I have two log files one is log4j2.xml and other is log4j.properties file.
log4j.properties file is created to set log level for org.hibernate package but I want this configured into same log4j2.xml. So how can I convert log4j.properties into xml format and append into log4j2.xml
Please find below the files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
   <Properties>
   <Property name="pattern">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</Property>
  </Properties>

  <Appenders>
     <RollingFile name="DailyRollingFile" fileName="${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/server.log"
             filePattern="$${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/server-%d{MM-dd-y 
             yyy}-%i.log.zip">
          <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
         <Policies>
            <!-- rotate every day -->
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
           <!-- or when size reaches 100 MB -->
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100MB"/>
        </Policies>
       <!-- Keep 30 files compressed -->
     <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30" compressionLevel="5"/>
   </RollingFile>
 </Appenders>
 <Loggers>

  <Logger name="com.bwcb.erv" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="DailyRollingFile"/>
   </Logger>
    <Root level="ERROR">
     <AppenderRef ref="DailyRollingFile"/>
   </Root>
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

log4j.properties file.

```
 #To configure third party log4j logging e.g Hibernate
 log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
 log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

 log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
 # basic log level for all messages
 log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable by using XML as

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>
```

or in file as

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
```

you can check more details about log4j [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)